# Explode long string - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a long string like: `B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5`, and i need to explode it on pairs so in this case `1 - B1 2 - C1` and so on...

The reason why i need that is that each pair contains 1 information in database so i have to take each of that pair and make some cycle or something to MySQL search

I was thinking about convert that sting to array like this:

```
1=> B1
2=> C1
3=> F4
```

and then foreach that with something like

```
foreach ($array as $arr)
{
  //and here come database search
}
```

But maybe i am completly wrong and to say true everything i try finish with ERROR so guys i am up for any advise, if somebody have time to write an example code it will be awesome.

Thanks!

p.s.
First of all i was thinking about something like:

```
$string[0] = substr($string,0,2);
$string[1] = substr($string,2,4);
```

but string will changing and I never know how long it will be

Comment: Hint: `substr` + `for` + `strlen`

Comment: `$array = str_split($string, 2);`

Comment: "but string will changing and I never know how long it will be" --- that's why you need `strlen`. Then just iterate from `0` up to `strlen` with `+ 2` step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [str_split()](http://php.net/str_split)

```
$str = 'B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5';
$ar = str_split($str,2);
print_r($ar);
```

Make sure you access the first element with zero index.

Comment: Actualy working and looks pretty easy :) Thumb up for that already. Is there a chance you can help me to write how can i PDO SQL statement for each of this pairs?

Comment: Glad to help! For PDO/SQL you should post another question, so people can find it separately :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always access a string like an array in itself without having to do anything to it like this:

```
$string='B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5';
for($i=0;$i<strlen($string)/2;$i++)
{
    $arr[]=$string[$i*2].$string[($i*2)+1];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Php function [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) might work

```
>>> $text = 'B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5'
>>> str_split($text, 2)
=> [
       "B1",
       "C1",
       "F4",
       "G6",
       "H4",
       "I7",
       "J1",
       "J8",
       "L5",
       "O6",
       "P2",
       "Q1",
       "R6",
       "T5",
       "U8",
       "V1",
       "Z5"
   ]
```

Comment: This looks good, so now I just need to foreach mysql command or what you suggest?

Comment: then you will have to traverse the array and do whatever operations you will need, str_split returns the array you will need

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion:

```
$string = "B1C1F4G6H4I7J1J8L5O6P2Q1R6T5U8V1Z5";
$array = recursion($string);

print_r($array);



function recursion ($string, $array = array()){
    if (strlen($string) < 1){
        return $array;
        }else{
            $array[] = substr($string, 0 ,2);
            return recursion(substr($string, 2), $array);
        }

}
```